# Real-time video render

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

We're staring a new project where we should be able to modify on the fly video - add text, insert image.
Project is planing to be written in Java.
I'm a newbie in video processing so I want to understand.
What is the best and fast solution to modify video and return to client (web browser).
I can easy do it using ffmpeg but mp4 is not streamable. And I should write it to file first and then return to client - it's not fast.
Maybe my question is very abstract but I should to start from somewhere :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you mention java, because it sounds to me as if you need to mix a stream of live video (from a camera) with alpha channel graphics etc. and then distribute it in realtime (like a TV station does?). Correct me if I misunderstand.

I suppose it all depends on the quality of the video you need to distribute, using a digital source like a webcam is not very exiting - although most modern products can do that too. It would be better to use a more professional camera with a decent optic that can send a quality stream to a software controlled video mixer & encoder (input card). Blackmagic do cheap mixers for this kind of thing (ATEM is cheap compared to other products in its class). Wirecast from Telestream is a very cheap alternative solution for doing the whole thing without having to buy additional encoders.

You need to send a stream to a distribution server. Depending on what you choose to buy (eg. you can use rather expensive H.264 or even JPEG2000 encoders and decoders with ATEM) If you do a cheaper rtmp stream with wirecast or such, you can handle the distribution with ffmpeg server - and there are other services and CDNs you can hook into if you use rtmp and want somebody to help you.